# R: Boxplot filled with its "label" color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fill the box with its color (like: blue ->blue).

```
goo1 <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Color, y=Scored.Probabilities)) +
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7)
print (goo1)
```

[image]

Data can be found here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zK9xcdOi1sUnNUZVpiXzN2c2c/view)

Comment: It's just different data size. I think the label is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scale (although you need to make sure first that every level of `dataset1$Persons` is indeed the name of a color recognized by R ; currently, `dark` and `game value` are not)

```
colors <- levels(dataset1$Color)
colors[colors == "dark"] <- "black"
colors[colors == "game value"] <- "cyan"

goo2 <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Color, y=Scored.Probabilities)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Color)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3)

goo2 <- goo2 + scale_fill_manual(values=colors)
```

Comment: Could I just define "dark" and "game value" as other color like "Black" and "Cyan"